# Cannot change resolution on LXDE

Tags: xrandr, lxde

I have Ubuntu 18.04 with LXDE at Nvidia Jetson Nano small computer and when monitor isnt attached I'm stuck with 640x480 resolution.
Launching Preferences-->"Monitor Settings" does not result with anything appearing on screen and "lxrandr" from terminal returns "Segmentation fault".

I then tried manually to add resolution 1280x768 but keep getting "cannot find output "S-video" or when changing mode to HDMI-0 getting "cannot find mode 1280x768" (see screenshot).

What could I do to change resolution? I'm accessing the device through NoMachine.

[image: Screenshot of attempts]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out! /etc/X11/xorg.conf  needs to be edited with:

```
Section "Screen"
   Identifier    "Default Screen"
   Monitor        "Configured Monitor"
   Device        "Default Device"
   SubSection "Display"
       Depth    24
       Virtual 1280 1024
   EndSubSection
EndSection
```